# ASP.NET detection of HttpHandler MVC vs. WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to understand and learn the architecture and pipeline of ASP.NET. So far I understand the architectural overview:

- on how we get from client to the IIS webserver (request)
- via ISAPI extension to the ASP.NET runtime
- from there on into the HTTP Pipeline
- and ASP.NET calling the HttpModules and HttpHandler
- in case of using MVC, selecting the `MvcHandler`
- which is returned by the `MvcRouteHandler`
- etc etc

Now what I don't understand (or can't find any resource on the web documentating this part), is how does the asp.net runtime detect which HttpHandler it has to select for it's request? So how does it know based on my Visual Studio solution that it's an MVC application for example? How does it figure it out that it should use the MvcHttpHandlers? Is there an assembly scan with Reflection somewhere in the HTTP pipeline? Because it certainly isn't a configuration telling the runtime to use the MvcHandler, or is it?
So basically at what exact point is the `HttpContext.CurrentHandler` being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Application_Start***
>
> When the request arrives to IIS and the endpoint corresponds to an
>   Asp.Net application, then the first event raised is the
>   **`Application_Start`** in the **`System.Web.HttpApplication`** object.

> ***RouteTable.Routes.Add***
>
> Into this event of an Mvc app you can set the routing rules that do
>   match endpoint urls with ***Controllers*** and ***Actions*** methods
>   in the application and the relative **`IRouteHandler`** object type,
>   that will be **`typeof(MvcRouteHandler)`**. 
>   *(see [Scott Guthrie post](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing))*

> ***HttpApplication.MapRequestHandler***
>
> Therefore, soon after that, when the routing table has been setted up,
>   in the subsequents events (or better in the methods that compose the
>   pipeline orchestrated by the Asp.Net Framework under IIS control
>   (***integrated pipeline***)) of the Asp.Net http request management,
>   when it needs to know how to manage the http request itself
>   (**`HttpApplication.MapRequestHandler`**), it get parsed the url in
>   the **`HttpContext`** object against the rules in the routing table,
>   and when it get found a matching, it is instatiated the right type of
>   its handler, **`MvcRouteHandler`** in our case, which will return the
>   **`IHttpHandler`** object by the method **`GetHttpHandler(RequestContext)`**: **`MvcHandler`** .
>   *(see [Msdn MvcRoutHandler.GetHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvcroutehandler.gethttphandler(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)))*

> ***MvcHandler.ProcessRequest***
>
> MvcHandler in turn, will give start to the real MVC request handling
>   through the Asp.Net pipeline event **`ProcessRequest`**: and so will
>   be instatiated the right ***Controller*** through the
>   **`ControllerFactory`**, and will be called the **`Execute`** method of the **`Controller`** abstract base class of the instatiated
>   controller object, and finally the right ***Action*** through the
>   **`ActionInvoker`**.
>   *(see [Msdn MvcHandler.ProcessRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler.processrequest(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)), and [The Asp.Net Mvc pipeline](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/))*

> ***final note on RouteCollection.MapRoute***
>  The Visual Studio starter template for MVC projects creates project that use **`MapRoute`** extension method
>   instead of **`RouteTable.Routes.Add`**. This method is very useful
>   because avoids to have to use always **`typeof(MvcRouteHandler)`**
>   expression when adding new url routing to the project. 
>   *(see [Asp.Net Routing and Asp.Net Mvc](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/aspnet-routing-and-aspnet-mvc-38085))*